# Parse a file of hex and split it up into 6-bit ints

Tags: c, arrays, hex

I've got a [file](https://github.com/flower/fvm/blob/master/examples/example.pot) containing hex code

```
 01F640
 01E120
 04EF20
 000000
```

and I want to add each 6 bits to an array. The array stores them as integers so the rest of the program can evaluate them. [Here is the code I have so far](https://github.com/flower/fvm/blob/master/fvm.c#L121-159).

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
   if(argc < 1){
     printf("You need to specify a file!");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   char ch;
   char chars[6];
   int charCount = 0;
   FILE *f;
   f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   while((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
     if(ch == '\n') continue;
     printf("r%X", ch);
     printf("\n");
     chars[i] = (char)ch;
     i++;
     if(i <= 6){
       i = 0;
       int hex[6];
       int m;
       for(m = 0; m < 6; m++){
         printf("\ns%X", chars[m]);
         char buffer[1];
         buffer[0] = chars[m];
         hex[m] = (int) strtol(buffer, NULL, 16);
       }
       unsigned int k = (hex[0]<<40)|(hex[1]<<32)|(hex[2]<<24)|(hex[3]<<16)|(hex[4]<<8)|hex[5];
       prog[j++] = k;
       memset(&chars[0], 0, sizeof(chars));
     }
   }

   int l;
   for(l = 0; l < PROG_LENGTH; l++){
     printf("p%X", prog[l]);
     if(prog[l] == 0) break;
   }
 }
```

What I'm trying to do is read each character and add it to an array of characters. Once that array has reached 6, create an int out of those bits and reset the array.

[Here are some recent builds from Travis](https://travis-ci.org/flower/fvm/builds).

Comment: You should edit your code and any additional documentation like a sample of your input directly into the question.  External links go bad.  You should also explain the specific problem you're having with your code.  Your description says what you're trying to do but not what isn't working.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Just added the external code, and I have no idea what's going wrong with it! :P I'll try some more debugging to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Six hexadecimal digits are more than six bits. It's three bytes.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just read the whole line and convert it to an integer with [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)?  Ideally your example should have some hex characters in it to make it very clear that they are not just 6 digit base 10 integers.

Comment: @EOF I meant six "digits" of hex numbers. I couldn't find a good name for it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I want it to read it up to six places, so I don't have to have each instruction on a new line (for compression).

Comment: @Phase Well, that is different than the example input you've shown.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The inputs don't matter as much, but I changed it to show some "hexy" letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the characters into a buffer and then use strtol

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
char buffer[7];
buffer[6] = '\0';
while((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
   if(ch == '\n') continue;
   buffer[i++] = ch;
   if(i == 6) {
      i = 0;
      prog[j++] = (int)strtol(buffer, NULL, 16);
   }
}
```

Comment: `fgets()`. Don't make it harder than it has to be.

Comment: But fgets would make it difficult to ignore newlines.

Comment: No, you just have to make the buffer large enough. *Your* solution fails for environments that use multiple characters to denote newline (`\r\n` or `\n\r`).